# How to create custom Popup menu in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

Hi i am newbie into flutter, how can i achieve custom `PopUpMenu` as shown in below screenshot.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrEyH.png)

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method **showDialog** to display an **AlertDialog** Widget.

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("PopUp title"),
            content: Text("PopUp content text"),
            actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(child: Text("Close"), onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context))
            ],
          );
        });
```